# Connect to Laravel Homestead, Vagrant running on Mac from iPad and iPhone

Tags: macos, ipad, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Is it possible to connect to my Laravel projects running on my Mac using Laravel Homestead from my iPad and iPhone?

When I go to the IP address of my Mac from either my iPad or iPhone I get the error:

**Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server.**

I'm sure I have done it in the past but I can't remember how. (That's if I did in the first place.)

Comment: You might want to look into [bridging](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) the Homestead network connection, so the virtual machine IP is accessible in your local netwerk.

Comment: Where is the Homestead vagrant file?

Comment: To expand slightly on @Bogdan's comment, Homestead uses virtualbox to expose the Homestead network to the Mac.  You would have to bridge the Homestead network so that way it is more 'one-in-the-same' as the Mac's network, not linked to it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? The link @Bogdan posted explains the `how` but not `where`

Answer (score 3):

By default, port 80 on the Vagrant VM is mapped to port 8000 on your computer. You should be able to open `http://<ipcomputer>:8000` on your iPhone/iPad.

If you have multiple sites defined in your `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` file, you will need to comment out the ones you don't want and provision the Vagrant machine again, otherwise, you cannot be sure which one of your sites will show up.

Comment: This is mostly correct and a good answer. A few notes - you will need to run `vagrant up --provision` for any alterations to the Homestead.yml. Additionally, the order isn't random, its alphabetical (so api.xyz.local will always appear before boo.xyz.local). This is an nginx "feature" (an annoying one at that)